# Mongodb: index on subdocument array

Tags: node.js, mongodb

So i have this structure of a document:

```
{
_id: "123abc",
mainProps: [
    {
        "countrycode": "US"
    },
    {
        "yearfounded": "2011"
    },
    {
        "city": "New York"
    },
    ...
],
otherProps: [{}, {}, ...]
}
```

I have an index set like this:

```
db.companies.ensureIndex({mainProps: 1})
```

The task is to create a webform for searching in these documents. Fields in the form are not fixed and can be added. Basically i don't know how what fields user would like to filter on, so I can't set proper compound index. Database will be more then 20mil documents, now it's about 10mil.

The problem is that my index doesn't work, or works wrong.
See some examples.

This query has no index at all.

```
db.companies.find({'mainProps.yearfounded': '2012'}).explain()
```

This query uses index and is fine.

```
db.companies.find({mainProps:{'yearfounded': '2012'}}).explain()
```

And something like this hangs (if I remove the explain() ) and I don't know whether it's executing or what's happening.

```
db.companies.find(
  {$or: [
    { mainProps: {foundedyear: '2012'}},
    { mainProps: {foundedyear: '2011'}},
  ]}
).explain()
```

For the last query explain I got something like this.

```
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
            "plannerVersion" : 1,
            "namespace" : "leadsbase.companies",
            "indexFilterSet" : false,
            "parsedQuery" : {
                    "$or" : [
                            {
                                    "mainProps" : {
                                            "$eq" : {
                                                    "foundedyear" : "2012"
                                            }
                                    }
                            },
                            {
                                    "mainProps" : {
                                            "$eq" : {
                                                    "foundedyear" : "2011"
                                            }
                                    }
                            }
                    ]
            },
            "winningPlan" : {
                    "stage" : "SUBPLAN",
                    "inputStage" : {
                            "stage" : "FETCH",
                            "inputStage" : {
                                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                    "keyPattern" : {
                                            "mainProps" : 1
                                    },
                                    "indexName" : "mainProps_1",
                                    "isMultiKey" : true,
                                    "isUnique" : false,
                                    "isSparse" : false,
                                    "isPartial" : false,
                                    "indexVersion" : 1,
                                    "direction" : "forward",
                                    "indexBounds" : {
                                            "mainProps" : [
                                                    "[{ foundedyear: \"2011\
" }, { foundedyear: \"2011\" }]",
                                                    "[{ foundedyear: \"2012\
" }, { foundedyear: \"2012\" }]"
                                            ]
                                    }
                            }
                    }
            },
            "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
            "host" : "vm1",
            "port" : 27017,
            "version" : "3.2.8",
            "gitVersion" : "ed70e33130c977bda0024c125b56d159573dbag0"
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

So as far as I understand index is present, but for some reason not working.

How should I structure my fields or how should I set indexes for this?

Comment: why do you say the last query does not use index scan, when the winningplan says to use IXSCAN?

Comment: >"So as far as I understand index is present, but for some reason not working."

I don't quite understand what's happening, but executing this without "explain" takes forever, even if I change "find" to "count"

Answer (score 0):

createIndex() will create indexes on collections whereas ensureIndex() creates an index on the specified field if the index does not already exist.
so your second query works while the firstQuery fails. try to delete your index with [dropIndex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.dropIndex/)(), and then rebuild the index with [createIndex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/)()

---

One way to check the performance o your indexscan , you can check for "executionStats"

```
   db.collection.explain("executionStats").find( <your query>)
```

and then from the result, check for this two field:

```
   executionSuccess.totalKeysExamined, executionSuccess.totalDocsExamined
```

For most case, if your index is good, both should have same number. Or you can read more in [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/analyze-query-plan/)

```
"executionStats" : {
   "executionSuccess" : <boolean>,
   "nReturned" : <int>,
   "executionTimeMillis" : <int>,
   "totalKeysExamined" : <int>,  // this is your index keys
   "totalDocsExamined" : <int>,  // this is total docs examined
   "executionStages" : {
      "stage" : <STAGE1>
      "nReturned" : <int>,
      "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : <int>,
      "works" : <int>,
      "advanced" : <int>,
      "needTime" : <int>,
      "needYield" : <int>,
      "isEOF" : <boolean>,
      ...
      "inputStage" : {
         "stage" : <STAGE2>,
         ...
         "nReturned" : <int>,
         "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : <int>,
         "keysExamined" : <int>,
         "docsExamined" : <int>,
         ...
         "inputStage" : {
            ...
         }
      }
   },
```

Comment: When i do 
`db.companies.find(
  {$or: [
    { mainProps: {foundedyear: '2012'}},
    { mainProps: {foundedyear: '2011'}},
  ]}
).explain("executionStats")`
 console just hangs. Without parameters it's okay. Maybe there's another problem with my mongo?

Comment: hi you should put, explain() before not after find(). if you put after, the console will try to run your queries first,

Comment: Worked this way. Got this: [link](http://codebeautify.org/online-json-editor/cb77b1cc) .Execution time is too huge for me (37s.), why is it almost instant with my second query?

Comment: ensureIndex() make index on field level and is deprecated, you should use createIndex() . I will update the answer

Comment: Thanks. I will try and post the result.

Comment: Seems that nothing changed. Something bigger than a single field query is slow like hell. It seems that ensureIndex is just an alias for createIndex, so there's no difference. [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.ensureIndex/)

Comment: it's not just an alias, if you read both. ensureIndex is indexing on field.. field is like property in JS object..createIndex is indexing on collection level, collection is like JS Object.. if you index on single-field query, it might not work on 2field query... Most of time, you need to put the index query as first field, unindexfield as second field..